# Jar version Compatibility Matrix among Java Technologies?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, maven

Upgrading from Java 1.7 to Java 1.8.

Is there any documentation for Jar version Compatibility Matrix among Java Technologies(like Java, J2EE, Spring Core, Spring JDBC, Spring Security, CXF SOAP, CXF REst, Maven, Maven Clean Plugin, Maven Compiler Plugin, Log4j, Jackson Parser and etc..)

Randomly we are changing the JAR versions while facing the JAR conflict issues.

Thank you in Advance!.

Comment: It's a huge effort to keep all these libraries in single place and validating all their dependencies. Usually technology dependencies are expressed per library, and it's up to individual developers to compare and work out what version of what library they should use.

Comment: Or, you know, use things that built for dependency management purposes, like Maven.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov: Yes maven helps lot but while deployment we are facing more issues due to jar conflicts. Resolving those issues by changing higher or lower version of same jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for compatibility reports in https://abi-laboratory.pro/java/tracker/.

Example report for [Spring Core](https://abi-laboratory.pro/java/tracker/timeline/spring-core/):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These are well documented libraries - You'll have to dig into the reference documentation/release history for that major milestone (Java 8 Support).

[Here's an example for Spring Framework that from version 4.0 onwards provided support for Java 8](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#_java_8_as_well_as_6_and_7).

Answer (score 1):

After analysis I have come up with JAR matrix among Java, J2EE, J2SE, Apache Maven, Spring, LOGGER, Apache CXF (SOAP/RESTFul), Jackson & GSON. Small POC has done and verified in JBOSS 4X and Web Logic 10 X. Will keep updated for the remaining components

**Maven**

1. maven version - 3.3.9
2. maven.compiler.plugin - 3.6.1
3. maven.clean.plugin - 3.0.0
4. maven.war.plugin - 3.1.0

**Java/J2EE/J2SE**

1. jdk version-1.7 / 1.8
2. servlet-api - 2.5
3. mail - 1.4.7
4. javax.ws.rs-api - 2.0.1
5. jaxb-core - 2.2.11
6. jaxb-impl - 2.2.11
7. javax.annotation-api - 1.2
8. aopalliance  - 1.0
9. asm - 5.0.4
10. javassist - 3.20.0-GA
11. stax-api - 1.0-2
12. jstl - 1.2

**Spring**

1. spring  - 2.5.6
2. spring-aop  - 4.3.8.RELEASE
3. spring-asm  - 3.1.4.RELEASE
4. spring-aspects   - 4.3.8.RELEASE
5. spring-beans     - 4.3.8.RELEASE
6. spring-context   - 4.3.8.RELEASE
7. spring-context-support   - 4.3.8.RELEASE
8. spring-core  - 4.3.8.RELEASE
9. spring-dao   - 2.0.8
10. spring-expression    - 4.3.8.RELEASE
11. spring-jdbc  - 4.3.8.RELEASE
12. spring-jms   - 4.3.8.RELEASE
13. spring-jmx   - 2.0.8
14. spring-orm   - 4.3.8.RELEASE
15. spring-oxm   - 4.3.8.RELEASE
16. spring-support   - 2.0.8
17. spring-test  - 4.3.8.RELEASE
18. spring-tx    - 4.3.8.RELEASE
19. spring-web   - 4.3.8.RELEASE
20. spring-webmvc    - 4.3.8.RELEASE
21. spring-webmvc-portlet    - 4.3.8.RELEASE
22. spring-webflow   - 2.4.4.RELEASE
23. spring-js-resources  - 2.4.4.RELEASE
24. spring-js    - 2.4.4.RELEASE
25. spring-binding   - 2.4.4.RELEASE
26. spring-batch-core    - 3.0.7.RELEASE
27. spring-batch-infrastructure  - 3.0.7.RELEASE
28. spring-batch-parent  - 3.0.7.RELEASE

**Apache CXF (SOAP/Restful)**

1. cxf-api  - 3.1.11
2. cxf-common-schemas   - 3.1.11
3. cxf-common-utilities     - 3.1.11
4. cxf-rt-bindings-jbi  - 3.1.11
5. cxf-rt-bindings-soap     - 3.1.11
6. cxf-rt-bindings-xml  - 3.1.11
7. cxf-rt-core  - 3.1.11
8. cxf-rt-databinding-aegis     - 3.1.11
9. cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb  - 3.1.11
10. cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs    - 3.1.11
11. cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws    - 3.1.11
12. cxf-rt-frontend-simple   - 3.1.11
13. cxf-rt-management    - 3.1.11
14. cxf-rt-transports-common     - 3.1.11
15. cxf-rt-transports-http   - 3.1.11
16. cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty     - 3.1.11
17. cxf-rt-transports-jms    - 3.1.11
18. cxf-rt-ws-addr   - 3.1.11
19. cxf-rt-ws-policy     - 3.1.11
20. cxf-rt-ws-rm     - 3.1.11
21. cxf-rt-ws-security   - 3.1.11
22. cxf-tools-common     - 3.1.11

**JSON Parser**

***Jackson (codehaus)***

1. jackson-jaxrs   - 1.9.13
2. jackson-core-asl    - 1.9.13
3. jackson-mapper-asl  - 1.9.13

***Jackson (fasterxml)***

1. jackson-databind    - 2.8.8
2. jackson-core     - 2.8.8
3. jackson-annotations - 2.8.8

***GSON***

1. gson    - 2.8.0

**Logger**

1. log4j   - 1.2.17